# C++ read-only array literal

Tags: c++, literals, string-literals

The possibility to create a array literal on read-only memory, exists as the string literal, but doesn't look to extend to other types.

```
const char* const kChar1{"This is a name"};
const char kChar2[]={"This is a name"};

const int* const kInt1{5,3,2,6,9,0,0,2};  //error
const int kInt2[]{5,3,2,6,9,0,0,2};
```

I can't create KInt1, like I created kChar1.

How could I create the equivalent?

Comment: C++ doesn't have array literals. What's wrong with using `kInt2`?

Comment: @RSahu OP wants to create the array in read-only memory

Comment: String literals aren't necessarily stored in read only memory... it's left to the implementation; the effect of trying to write to it is undefined though.  There's very rarely a reason to want something like `kChar1`... just wastes space for an extra pointer.

Comment: @TonyD could you elaborate on that? Probably both kChar1 and kChar2 can be optimized in most cases to produce the same code, but disregarding that, kChar2 would consume data memory to store the entire string, and code memory to initialize it. Are you sure kChar2 is always or at least most of the times a better solution?

Comment: @nunojpg: actually `static const char kChar3[] = {"This is a name"};` is best in practice on the compilers I've tried... just uses the read-only data segment.  Without `static` GCC and MSVC copy to a stack-based array even though the variable's marked `const` - I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly close:

```
const int kInt2[]{5,3,2,6,9,0,0,2};
const int* const kInt1 = kInt2;
```

The only real difference is that kInt1 will necessarily point to the same memory as kInt2, but kChar1 does not necessarily point to the same memory as kChar2.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is correct

```
const int one = 5;
const int two = 10;
const int* const kInt1[] ={&one,&two};
```